# Access Denied for s3:PutObjectACL even after giving permissions for role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I've used `putobjectacl` boto3 API in a lambda function, I've given the below permissions to my lambda function, still getting the below error saying Access Denied for Putobjectacl operation.

**Lambda Permissions:**

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket-name/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

**ERROR:**

```bash
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObjectAcl operation: Access Denied
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please show us your code that generates this error.

Comment: Does the bucket have a bucket policy?

Comment: Bucket owner enforced set for [S3 Object Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-ownership-new-bucket.html) thus disabling ACLs?

Comment: Please post your bucket policy. The bucket policy may block access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the above issue, ensure the following:

- **Block public Access** should be Disabled in the Bucket config

  - To check, Open S3 Bucket  > Permissions > Block public access (bucket settings) > Uncheck the checkbox > Save  Changes
- **ACL**s should be Enabled

  - To check, Open S3 Bucket > Permissions > Object Ownership > ACLs Enabled

In my case, bucket public access was enabled.